# How can I save multiple user input to a spinner?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, save

I am working with c# on Xamarin, Visual studio 2015 to develop android app. I have a box where user have to input a string value then when a button clicked, I want this value to be added to a spinner and to be saved and reloaded for the next open so he can choose the value he entered without the need to re-input it. Till now I don"t have a problem, I got my idea worked. But what I am struggling in is: if a user have input a value then clicked the button, then entered another value, only the last value is saved and showed in the spinner when the APP is re-opened. What I want is: each value entered by the user need to be saved and showed in the spinner. Then if the user want to delete the value he entered before, a button for delete item.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
string user;
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
var items = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
Button button4 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);
Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
EditText input = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.input);
user = input.Text;
button4.Click += delegate
        {
            user = input.Text;
            items.Add(user);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
            editor.PutString("try", user);
            editor.Apply();
        };
user = prefs.GetString("try", "no");
items.Add(user);
var adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
spinner.Adapter = adapter3;
```

Those code are adding and saving the user input to the spinner when I reopen the app but if the user entered two values then only the last one is saved. What I want is each value to be saved and displayed in the spinner.
Thank you in advance..

Comment: You are only saving the most recent value to prefs.  If you want to store multiple values, you'll need to store them in an array or list and serialize them to prefs.

Comment: Use putStringSet to store collection of strings in SharedPrefence then use getStringSet to populate spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    // a constant to avoid magic strings
    const string KEY_FOR_TRY = "TRY";

    ArrayAdapter<string> _spinnerAdapter;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        string user;
        ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);

        // Load the items from pref and fill the spinner
        // if pref is empty just set an empty list.
        // GetStringSet because you are loading the collection you saved.
        var savedItems = prefs.GetStringSet (KEY_FOR_TRY, new List<string> ());

        var items = new List<string> (savedItems);

        Button button4 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button4);
        Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinner1);
        EditText input = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.input);
        user = input.Text;

        button4.Click += delegate
                {
                    //you might want validate for empty strings and if entry is already saved to prevent duplicates.
                    user = input.Text;
                    items.Add (user);
                    ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();

                    //PutStringSet because you are saving a collection.
                    editor.PutStringSet (KEY_FOR_TRY, items);
                    editor.Apply ();
                     //do this only if you want to refresh the spinner values.
                    _spinnerAdapter.Insert (user, 0);
                    _spinnerAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
                };

        //Get the first item if there is any, don't know why you need this.
        user = items.FirstOrDefault ();

        _spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);

        spinner.Adapter = _spinnerAdapter;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's working well but  I want my spinner to contain (1,2,3) as default then if the user wants to add another value he can do so.. As I showed in my code: the var items contain "1,2,3" and it was set as an adapter for my spinner. In addition, I haven't understand the meaning of _spinneradapter.Insert(user, 0) and _spinneradapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() in your code.

Comment: Also I want to have a button to delete item if the user wanted to remove one of the value he entered. Also I don't want the user to enter two same values or enter a null value. @apineda